# Xampp mysql funny datetime displayed

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have created a table in my new computer with script used in my old computer and I have copied 3 data files; `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1` and `ibdata1` too. I can see the table created in this new computer including its contents. All columns have correct value except the a column with `datetime` value. It has values like `1195-11-23 21:41:17`, `9707-10-07 26:22:47` and `9707-10-07 26:22:47` etc. I expect it to be something like `2014-7-26 21:30:10`.

It looks like minute and second are correct but the hour, day, month and year are totally out. Please advise what need to be configure in Xampp. Thanks.

Comment: Was the version of MySQL the same on the 2 machines?? When you say _I have created a table in my new computer with script used in my old computer_ Do you mean you ran a Restore of a backup, or something else??

Comment: Yes, same version. My old computer was 32 bits but I installed 32 bits version in my new 64 bits computer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I installed 32 bits Xampp which is bundle of MySQL, php, perl etc.

Comment: BTW, I have capture an image of the display. http://i.imgur.com/wU2b26O.png

Comment: So how exactly did you restore the table, can you show some of the script you ran?

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly for the follow up.

Comment: Does that mean you fixed your problems?

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly for the follow up. Let me brief you on what I did. First I installed Xampp on my new computer (64 bits), using the installer xampp-win32-5.6.3-0-VC11-installer.exe, downloaded from the website. Next I created the database in phpMyAdmin. Then I created the table. After that I copied 3 data files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 and ibdata1) from my old computer to the directory C:\Program Files (x86)xampp\mysql\data.

Comment: I opened the database table, templog, and able to see all columns filled up without error. I went on to reformat my old computer and donated it to a charity. A day later when I tried using my javascript to query the table I found the date was all very weird (shown on the image, column trans_date).

Comment: I am confident that the method was right as I did it before, transferring data from Window 7 to another Window 7. This time it was Window 7 to Window 8 (and 32 bits to 64 bits). I believe the date was not stored as it appear but coded in certain format and the interpretation differ.

Comment: Other columns have no problem, filled up with correct values. Please advise if any setup is required for the datetime datatype. Thanks.

Comment: Well quite obviously the raw databases are not totally compatible between these 2 systems or you missed something important when saving the old data. Backing up and recovering INNODB databases is normally a bit more complicated than that. [See the Docmentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html)

Comment: Ok thanks RiggsFolly. I will figure out what is missing, I see something with the documentation link you provided. Regards.